# Electromagnetic Profile for CME over time in the region of a geostationary satellite?

Tags: coronal-mass-ejection

My specific question is what/how would the electromagnetic field profile be over time for a coronal mass ejection at the orbital radii for a typical geostationary orbit at around 35 000 km be?

The specific application of this is in relation to a satellite and the effects on the internal systems. But first I would like to establish the how the parameters of the electromagnetic fields may evolve over some kind of time-scale in the case of such an event.